# Spring Security 3.1 And The Right Jars

Tags: spring-security

I'm using Spring 3.1 and I am doing LDAP for the first time.

Here is my *-security.xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

  <http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome"
      authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
  </http>

  <ldap-server url = "ldap://ldap-east.abc.acme.org:636/o=acme.org" />

    <authentication-manager>
      <ldap-authentication-provider user-dn-pattern="uid={0},ou=people"/>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

I started with these security related jars in my lib:

```
spring-security-ldap-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-config-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-taglibs-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
```

And I got this error message:

> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: 
>       Couldn't locate: org.springframework.ldap.core.support.BaseLdapPathContextSource.
>       If you are using LDAP with Spring Security, 
>       please ensure that you include the spring-ldap jar file in your application; 
>       nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
>       org.springframework.ldap.core.support.BaseLdapPathContextSource

So, I added more jars to lib to be this set of security files:

```
spring-ldap-core-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-ldap-core-tiger-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-ldap-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-config-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-taglibs-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
```

That got me in deeper with even MORE error messages:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' 
while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0' 
while setting constructor argument with key [2]; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0':
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' w
hile setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0' 
while setting constructor argument; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0': 
FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider#0' 
while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider#0': 
Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator] 
while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#17': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.securityContextSource' 
while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.securityContextSource': 
Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource]: 
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundE
```

I'm catching up on a lot of things, learning Maven is on my list, but I am not there yet.  Any tips on getting the right mix jars to do a basic LDAP authentication with Spring 3.1?

**I tried loading the entire Spring 3.1.1 dist, the entire Spring LDAP 1.3.1 dist and the entire Spring Security 3.1.0 dist.   I've got everything.  So I am at a loss to see how this is a dependency issue, FWIW.**

Comment: org.springframework.ldap.core.support.BaseLdapPathContextSource is inside spring-security-ldap jar. Maybe is not a jar problem but a classpath one. Review your classpath

Comment: jddsantaella, how would it be a classpath problem?  All of the jars mentioned were in my war/WEB-INF/lib directory.  Thanks.

Comment: I tried loading the entire Spring 3.1.1 dist, the entire Spring LDAP 1.3.1 dist and the entire Spring Security 3.1.0 dist into my war/WEB-INF/lib.  I've got everything. So I am at a loss to see how this is a dependency issue, FWIW.

Answer (score 7):

```
spring-security-config
spring-security-taglibs
spring-security-ldap
```

Those 3 should be enough and they will pull their dependendies if you are using maven or similar tool.

If not, you need to go through all 3 libs and copy all their dependencies as well in your classpath.

[image: Dependency graph]

Comment: Like I wrote, I am doing a lot of catch up learning.  Maven is on my list.  I'm not there yet though.  Any suggestions for finding the dependencies for those three jars without using Maven? Thanks.

Comment: I found this list of dependencies.  I'll let everyone know if it does the trick: [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#appendix-dependencies)

Comment: see above for dependency graph. You should start using maven, will make several things easier for you about the dependencies.

Comment: fmucar, that chart is a great advertisement for Maven. LOL :)

Comment: It is on my list and after today, I may move it up ahead of some other things I need to study.

Answer (score 2):

Check this thread [Moved to Spring 3.1.1 from Spring 3.0.5 now my App does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586971/moved-to-spring-3-1-1-from-spring-3-0-5-now-my-app-does-not-work)

As ryan-stewart states:

> Blockquote spring-ldap isn't included with the base spring 3.1 distro. In fact, its versioning is completely separate, and it's presently at version 1.3.1.

You need to download the extra jars from [here](http://www.springsource.org/download/community?project=Spring%2520LDAP)

All the credit goes to [ryan-stewart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/839646/ryan-stewart)