# Moved to Spring 3.1.1 from Spring 3.0.5 now my App does not work

Tags: spring, spring-security

Moved to Spring 3.1.1 from Spring 3.0.5 now my App does not work can someone please tell me what is up? I removed all the 3.0.5 jars and added the 3.1.1 jars

```
2012-05-14 12:01:41,195 [main] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Couldn't locate: org.springframework.ldap.core.support.BaseLdapPathContextSource.  If you are using LDAP with Spring Security, please ensure that you include the spring-ldap jar file in your application; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.ldap.core.support.BaseLdapPathContextSource
    at org.springframework.security.config.ldap.ContextSourceSettingPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ContextSourceSettingPostProcessor.java:34)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:664)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.ldap.core.support.BaseLdapPathContextSource
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:258)
    at org.springframework.security.config.ldap.ContextSourceSettingPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ContextSourceSettingPostProcessor.java:32)
    ... 21 more
May 14, 2012 12:01:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Couldn't locate: org.springframework.ldap.core.support.BaseLdapPathContextSource.  If you are using LDAP with Spring Security, please ensure that you include the spring-ldap jar file in your application; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.ldap.core.support.BaseLdapPathContextSource
    at org.springframework.security.config.ldap.ContextSourceSettingPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ContextSourceSettingPostProcessor.java:34)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681)
```

Comment: Have you updated xml file namespaces/schema locations?

Answer (score 3):

Have you done what it suggests and verified that spring-ldap is included with your app? That's [clearly where the class in question lives](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3a%22org.springframework.ldap.core.support.BaseLdapPathContextSource%22). My guess is that you blindly removed all the jars named spring-* and added in all the 3.1 spring-* jar files, but spring-ldap [isn't included with the base spring 3.1 distro](http://www.springsource.org/ldap). In fact, its versioning is completely separate, and it's [presently at version 1.3.1](http://www.springsource.com/download/community?project=Spring%20LDAP).